# lock doesn't work with redis-py - unknown command 'EVALSHA'

Tags: python, redis, locking, redis-py

The following creates, acquires and releases a lock in redis:

```
import redis

redis_url = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/'
redis_conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

l = redis_conn.lock('lock-test')
l.acquire()
l.release()
```

How come upon `acquire()` the following error is thrown?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/myproj/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    l.acquire()
  File "C:\dev\myproj\venv_myproj\lib\site-packages\redis\lock.py", line 111, in acquire
    if self.do_acquire(token):
  File "C:\dev\myproj\venv_myproj\lib\site-packages\redis\lock.py", line 258, in do_acquire
    client=self.redis))
  File "C:\dev\myproj\venv_myproj\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 2646, in __call__
    return client.evalsha(self.sha, len(keys), *args)
  File "C:\dev\myproj\venv_myproj\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 1911, in evalsha
    return self.execute_command('EVALSHA', sha, numkeys, *keys_and_args)
  File "C:\dev\myproj\venv_myproj\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 565, in execute_command
    return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
  File "C:\dev\myproj\venv_myproj\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 577, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "C:\dev\myproj\venv_myproj\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 574, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command 'EVALSHA'
```

My setup: python 2.7.8, [redis 2.4.5 64bit](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1335598545/redis-ported-to-windows), win8

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to latest redis solved this for me.
I ended up building version 2.8.16 from [this repo](https://github.com/msopenTech/redis/) using VS13

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The problem was happening with redis 2.2.xxx.